# accessing name of an index in a list

Tags: r

With a list like below

```
mapping <- c( "All A"= list(c('a1', 'a2')), "All B" = list(c('b1', 'b2')))
```

I can access the vector in index 1 as below

```
> mapping[[1]]
[1] "a1" "a2"
```

How do I get the name of list at index 1 - i.e `All A`

Comment: Isn't this essentially a different way of asking [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849296/dplyr-ifelse-within-mutate-using-list) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the names function:

```
> names(mapping)
[1] "All A" "All B"
> names(mapping)[1]
[1] "All A"
```